# Talk about A more than B vs talk more about A than B

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which sentence has the correct grammar?

> 1. I talk about A more than B.
> 2. I talk more about A than B.

I think the first one is correct, while my friend uses the second one.

> Dr. Karp’s interview may ask children if they miss their biological parents or how long it has been since they saw their parents last time, all of which would sway them toward talking more about their biological parents than **do** other adults in the village.

The above sentence is what my friend wrote. I think the word, do, is redundant. Am I correct? Also, which one, "talk about A more than B" or "talk more about A than B", should we use in this sentence?

Comment: Both are possible. I would understand (1) to mean 'I talk about A more often than I do about B', and (2) to mean 'I have more to say about A than about B'.

Comment: Please only ask one question at once. For what it's worth, the inclusion or omission of *do* **completely** changes the comparison in that sentence. It may be that its inclusion does not produce the desired result, but we don't know what the desired result is.

Comment: Right now, "children" are compared to "other adults," which seems off. Also, "biological parents" and "parents" are used interchangeably, which seems off.

Comment: English comparative syntax is notoriously confusing and difficult to state precisely. Semantically, comparatives involve two quantifiers and an inequality relation between them, a logical complex that gets shredded by the requirements of sentence grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adverbs are pretty flexible in English. Many can be placed anywhere in the sentence to retain the same meaning. Others imply different things based on where they are placed.

*Talk more about*, to me, implies that the talking is at greater length.
*Talk about more*, to me is equal to "talk about more often."

For instance if an interviewer says "Would you talk more about your father" or "Would you talk about your father more" they are saying the same thing.

So... they can both have either meaning. Welcome to English ambiguity. :)